# How can I see the default baud rate of the turtlebot_node.py file?

Tags: ros, roomba, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!!!

I'm newbie in this but I'm trying to use the TurtleBot package in a Roomba 600, but I can't, I think that is by the default rate, but I don't where is the line code to change it, because my robot is working with a baudrate of 115200 and I've read that the old Roomba worked with a default baudrate of 57600. I've opened the turtlebot_node.py file, which it is in  `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/create_node/`, and this is the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# Software License Agreement (BSD License)
#
# Copyright (c) 2010, Willow Garage, Inc.
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
#  * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#  * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
#    copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
#    disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
#    with the distribution.
#  * Neither the name of Willow Garage, Inc. nor the names of its
#    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
#    from this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
# INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
# BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
# LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
# CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
# LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
# ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
# POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# Revision $Id: __init__.py 11217 2010-09-23 21:08:11Z kwc $

    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('create_node')

"""
ROS Turtlebot node for ROS built on top of create_driver's
turtlebot implementation. This driver is based on 
otl_roomba by OTL (otl-ros-pkg).

create_driver's turtlebot implementation is based on 
Damon Kohler's pyrobot.py.
"""

import os
import sys
import select
import serial
import termios
import time

from math import sin, cos

import rospkg
import rospy
import tf

from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Pose, Pose2D, PoseWithCovariance, \
    Quaternion, Twist, TwistWithCovariance, Vector3
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState

from create_driver import Turtlebot, MAX_WHEEL_SPEED, DriverError
from create_node.msg import TurtlebotSensorState, Drive, Turtle
from create_node.srv import SetTurtlebotMode,SetTurtlebotModeResponse, SetDigitalOutputs, SetDigitalOutputsResponse
from create_node.diagnostics import TurtlebotDiagnostics
import create_node.robot_types as robot_types
from create_node.covariances import \
     ODOM_POSE_COVARIANCE, ODOM_POSE_COVARIANCE2, ODOM_TWIST_COVARIANCE, ODOM_TWIST_COVARIANCE2
from create_node.songs import bonus

#dynamic reconfigure
import dynamic_reconfigure.server
from create_node.cfg import TurtleBotConfig


class TurtlebotNode(object):

    _SENSOR_READ_RETRY_COUNT = 5 

    def __init__(self, default_port='/dev/ttyUSB0', default_update_rate=30.0):

        """
        @param default_port: default tty port to use for establishing
            connection to Turtlebot.  This will be overriden by ~port ROS
            param if available.
        """
        self.default_port = default_port
        self.default_update_rate = default_update_rate

        self.robot = Turtlebot()
        self.sensor_handler = None
        self.sensor_state = TurtlebotSensorState()
        self.req_cmd_vel = None

        rospy.init_node('turtlebot')
        self._init_params()
        self._init_pubsub()
        
        self._pos2d = Pose2D() # 2D pose for odometry

        self._diagnostics = TurtlebotDiagnostics()
        if self.has_gyro:
            from create_node.gyro import TurtlebotGyro
            self._gyro = TurtlebotGyro()
        else:
            self._gyro = None
            
        dynamic_reconfigure.server.Server(TurtleBotConfig, self.reconfigure)

    def start(self):
        log_once = True
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            try:
                self.robot.start(self.port, robot_types.ROBOT_TYPES[self.robot_type].baudrate)
                break
            except serial.serialutil.SerialException as ex:
                msg = "Failed to open port %s. Error: %s Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer. \n"%((self.port), ex.message)
                self._diagnostics.node_status(msg,"error")
                if log_once:
                    log_once = False
                    rospy.logerr(msg)
                else:
                    sys.stderr.write(msg)
                time.sleep(3.0)

        self.sensor_handler = robot_types.ROBOT_TYPES[self.robot_type].sensor_handler(self.robot) 
        self.robot.safe = True

        if rospy.get_param('~bonus', False):
            bonus(self.robot)

        self.robot.control()
        # Write driver state to disk
        with open(connected_file(), 'w') as f:
            f.write("1")

        # Startup readings from Create can be incorrect, discard first values
        s = TurtlebotSensorState()
        try:
            self.sense(s)
        except Exception:
            # packet read can get interrupted, restart loop to
            # check for exit conditions
            pass


    def _init_params(self):
        self.port = rospy.get_param('~port', self.default_port)
        self.robot_type = rospy.get_param('~robot_type', 'create')
        #self.baudrate = rospy.get_param('~baudrate', self.default_baudrate)
        self.update_rate = rospy.get_param('~update_rate', self.default_update_rate)
        self.drive_mode = rospy.get_param('~drive_mode', 'twist')
        self.has_gyro = rospy.get_param('~has_gyro', True)
        self.odom_angular_scale_correction = rospy.get_param('~odom_angular_scale_correction', 1.0)
        self.odom_linear_scale_correction = rospy.get_param('~odom_linear_scale_correction', 1.0)
        self.cmd_vel_timeout = rospy.Duration(rospy.get_param('~cmd_vel_timeout', 0.6))
        self.stop_motors_on_bump = rospy.get_param('~stop_motors_on_bump', True)
        self.min_abs_yaw_vel = rospy.get_param('~min_abs_yaw_vel', None)
        self.max_abs_yaw_vel = rospy.get_param('~max_abs_yaw_vel', None)
        self.publish_tf = rospy.get_param('~publish_tf', False)
        self.odom_frame = rospy.get_param('~odom_frame', 'odom')
        self.base_frame = rospy.get_param('~base_frame', 'base_footprint')
        self.operate_mode = rospy.get_param('~operation_mode', 3)

        rospy.loginfo("serial port: %s"%(self.port))
        rospy.loginfo("update_rate: %s"%(self.update_rate))
        rospy.loginfo("drive mode: %s"%(self.drive_mode))
        rospy.loginfo("has gyro: %s"%(self.has_gyro))

    def _init_pubsub(self):
        self.joint_states_pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
        self.odom_pub = rospy.Publisher('odom', Odometry, queue_size=10)

        self.sensor_state_pub = rospy.Publisher('~sensor_state', TurtlebotSensorState, queue_size=10)
        self.operating_mode_srv = rospy.Service('~set_operation_mode', SetTurtlebotMode, self.set_operation_mode)
        self.digital_output_srv = rospy.Service('~set_digital_outputs', SetDigitalOutputs, self.set_digital_outputs)

        if self.drive_mode == 'twist':
            self.cmd_vel_sub = rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel', Twist, self.cmd_vel)
            self.drive_cmd = self.robot.direct_drive
        elif self.drive_mode == 'drive':
            self.cmd_vel_sub = rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel', Drive, self.cmd_vel)
            self.drive_cmd = self.robot.drive
        elif self.drive_mode == 'turtle':
            self.cmd_vel_sub = rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel', Turtle, self.cmd_vel)
            self.drive_cmd = self.robot.direct_drive
        else:
            rospy.logerr("unknown drive mode :%s"%(self.drive_mode))

        self.transform_broadcaster = None
        if self.publish_tf:
            self.transform_broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
    
    def reconfigure(self, config, level):
        self.update_rate = config['update_rate']
        self.drive_mode = config['drive_mode']
        self.has_gyro = config['has_gyro']
        if self.has_gyro:
            self._gyro.reconfigure(config, level)
        self.odom_angular_scale_correction = config['odom_angular_scale_correction']
        self.odom_linear_scale_correction = config['odom_linear_scale_correction']
        self.cmd_vel_timeout = rospy.Duration(config['cmd_vel_timeout'])
        self.stop_motors_on_bump = config['stop_motors_on_bump']
        self.min_abs_yaw_vel = config['min_abs_yaw_vel']
        self.max_abs_yaw_vel = config['max_abs_yaw_vel']
        return config

    def cmd_vel(self, msg):
        # Clamp to min abs yaw velocity, to avoid trying to rotate at low
        # speeds, which doesn't work well.
        if self.min_abs_yaw_vel is not None and msg.angular.z != 0.0 and abs(msg.angular.z) < self.min_abs_yaw_vel:
            msg.angular.z = self.min_abs_yaw_vel if msg.angular.z > 0.0 else -self.min_abs_yaw_vel
        # Limit maximum yaw to avoid saturating the gyro
        if self.max_abs_yaw_vel is not None and self.max_abs_yaw_vel > 0.0 and msg.angular.z != 0.0 and abs(msg.angular.z) > self.max_abs_yaw_vel: 
            msg.angular.z = self.max_abs_yaw_vel if msg.angular.z > 0.0 else -self.max_abs_yaw_vel 
        if self.drive_mode == 'twist':
            # convert twist to direct_drive args
            ts  = msg.linear.x * 1000 # m -> mm
            tw  = msg.angular.z  * (robot_types.ROBOT_TYPES[self.robot_type].wheel_separation / 2) * 1000 
            # Prevent saturation at max wheel speed when a compound command is sent.
            if ts > 0:
                ts = min(ts,   MAX_WHEEL_SPEED - abs(tw))
            else:
                ts = max(ts, -(MAX_WHEEL_SPEED - abs(tw)))
            self.req_cmd_vel = int(ts - tw), int(ts + tw)
        elif self.drive_mode == 'turtle':
            # convert to direct_drive args
            ts  = msg.linear * 1000 # m -> mm
            tw  = msg.angular  * (robot_types.ROBOT_TYPES[self.robot_type].wheel_separation / 2) * 1000 
            self.req_cmd_vel = int(ts - tw), int(ts + tw)
        elif self.drive_mode == 'drive':
            # convert twist to drive args, m->mm (velocity, radius)
            self.req_cmd_vel = msg.velocity * 1000, msg.radius * 1000

    def set_operation_mode(self,req):
        if not self.robot.sci:
            rospy.logwarn("Create : robot not connected yet, sci not available")
            return SetTurtlebotModeResponse(False)

        self.operate_mode = req.mode

        if req.mode == 1: #passive
            self._robot_run_passive()
        elif req.mode == 2: #safe
            self._robot_run_safe()
        elif req.mode == 3: #full
            self._robot_run_full()
        else:
            rospy.logerr("Requested an invalid mode.")
            return SetTurtlebotModeResponse(False)
        return SetTurtlebotModeResponse(True)

    def _robot_run_passive(self):
        """
        Set robot into passive run mode
        """
        rospy.loginfo("Setting turtlebot to passive mode.")
        #setting all the digital outputs to 0
        self._set_digital_outputs([0, 0, 0])
        self.robot.passive()

    def _robot_reboot(self):
        """
        Perform a soft-reset of the Create
        """
        msg ="Soft-rebooting turtlebot to passive mode."
        rospy.logdebug(msg)
        self._diagnostics.node_status(msg,"warn")
        self._set_digital_outputs([0, 0, 0])
        self.robot.soft_reset()
        time.sleep(2.0)

    def _robot_run_safe(self):
        """
        Set robot into safe run mode
        """
        rospy.loginfo("Setting turtlebot to safe mode.")
        self.robot.safe = True
        self.robot.control()
        b1 = (self.sensor_state.user_digital_inputs & 2)/2
        b2 = (self.sensor_state.user_digital_inputs & 4)/4
        self._set_digital_outputs([1, b1, b2])



    def _robot_run_full(self):
        """
        Set robot into full run mode
        """
        rospy.loginfo("Setting turtlebot to full mode.")
        self.robot.safe = False
        self.robot.control()
        b1 = (self.sensor_state.user_digital_inputs & 2)/2
        b2 = (self.sensor_state.user_digital_inputs & 4)/4
        self._set_digital_outputs([1, b1, b2])



    def _set_digital_outputs(self, outputs):
        assert len(outputs) == 3, 'Expecting 3 output states.'
        byte = 0
        for output, state in enumerate(outputs):
            byte += (2 ** output) * int(state)
        self.robot.set_digital_outputs(byte)
        self.sensor_state.user_digital_outputs = byte

    def set_digital_outputs(self,req):
        if not self.robot.sci:
            raise Exception("Robot not connected, SCI not available")
            
        outputs = [req.digital_out_0,req.digital_out_1, req.digital_out_2]
        self._set_digital_outputs(outputs)
        return SetDigitalOutputsResponse(True)

    def sense(self, sensor_state):
        self.sensor_handler.get_all(sensor_state)
        if self._gyro:
            self._gyro.update_calibration(sensor_state)

    def spin(self):

        # state
        s = self.sensor_state
        odom = Odometry(header=rospy.Header(frame_id=self.odom_frame), child_frame_id=self.base_frame)
        js = JointState(name = ["left_wheel_joint", "right_wheel_joint", "front_castor_joint", "back_castor_joint"],
                        position=[0,0,0,0], velocity=[0,0,0,0], effort=[0,0,0,0])

        r = rospy.Rate(self.update_rate)
        last_cmd_vel = 0, 0
        last_cmd_vel_time = rospy.get_rostime()
        last_js_time = rospy.Time(0)
        # We set the retry count to 0 initially to make sure that only 
        # if we received at least one sensor package, we are robust 
        # agains a few sensor read failures. For some strange reason, 
        # sensor read failures can occur when switching to full mode 
        # on the Roomba. 
        sensor_read_retry_count = 0 


        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            last_time = s.header.stamp
            curr_time = rospy.get_rostime()

            # SENSE/COMPUTE STATE
            try:
                self.sense(s)
                transform = self.compute_odom(s, last_time, odom)
                # Future-date the joint states so that we don't have
                # to publish as frequently.
                js.header.stamp = curr_time + rospy.Duration(1)
            except select.error:
                # packet read can get interrupted, restart loop to
                # check for exit conditions
                continue

            except DriverError: 
                if sensor_read_retry_count > 0: 
                    rospy.logwarn('Failed to read sensor package. %d retries left.' % sensor_read_retry_count) 
                    sensor_read_retry_count -= 1 
                    continue 
                else: 
                    raise 
            sensor_read_retry_count = self._SENSOR_READ_RETRY_COUNT 

            # Reboot Create if we detect that charging is necessary.
            if s.charging_sources_available > 0 and \
                   s.oi_mode == 1 and \
                   s.charging_state in [0, 5] and \
                   s.charge < 0.93*s.capacity:
                rospy.loginfo("going into soft-reboot and exiting driver")
                self._robot_reboot()
                rospy.loginfo("exiting driver")
                break

            # Reboot Create if we detect that battery is at critical level switch to passive mode.
            if s.charging_sources_available > 0 and \
                   s.oi_mode == 3 and \
                   s.charging_state in [0, 5] and \
                   s.charge < 0.15*s.capacity:
                rospy.loginfo("going into soft-reboot and exiting driver")
                self._robot_reboot()
                rospy.loginfo("exiting driver")
                break

            # PUBLISH STATE
            self.sensor_state_pub.publish(s)
            self.odom_pub.publish(odom)
            if self.publish_tf:
                self.publish_odometry_transform(odom)
            # 1hz, future-dated joint state
            if curr_time > last_js_time + rospy.Duration(1):
                self.joint_states_pub.publish(js)
                last_js_time = curr_time
            self._diagnostics.publish(s, self._gyro)
            if self._gyro:
                self._gyro.publish(s, last_time)

            # ACT
            if self.req_cmd_vel is not None:
                # check for velocity command and set the robot into full mode if not plugged in
                if s.oi_mode != self.operate_mode and s.charging_sources_available != 1:
                    if self.operate_mode == 2:
                        self._robot_run_safe()
                    else:
                        self._robot_run_full()

                # check for bumper contact and limit drive command
                req_cmd_vel = self.check_bumpers(s, self.req_cmd_vel)

                # Set to None so we know it's a new command
                self.req_cmd_vel = None
                # reset time for timeout
                last_cmd_vel_time = last_time

            else:
                #zero commands on timeout
                if last_time - last_cmd_vel_time > self.cmd_vel_timeout:
                    last_cmd_vel = 0,0
                # double check bumpers
                req_cmd_vel = self.check_bumpers(s, last_cmd_vel)

            # send command
            self.drive_cmd(*req_cmd_vel)
            # record command
            last_cmd_vel = req_cmd_vel

            r.sleep()

    def check_bumpers(self, s, cmd_vel):
        # Safety: disallow forward motion if bumpers or wheeldrops
        # are activated.
        # TODO: check bumps_wheeldrops flags more thoroughly, and disable
        # all motion (not just forward motion) when wheeldrops are activated
        forward = (cmd_vel[0] + cmd_vel[1]) > 0
        if self.stop_motors_on_bump and s.bumps_wheeldrops > 0 and forward:
            return (0,0)
        else:
            return cmd_vel

    def compute_odom(self, sensor_state, last_time, odom):
        """
        Compute current odometry.  Updates odom instance and returns tf
        transform. compute_odom() does not set frame ids or covariances in
        Odometry instance.  It will only set stamp, pose, and twist.

        @param sensor_state: Current sensor reading
        @type  sensor_state: TurtlebotSensorState
        @param last_time: time of last sensor reading
        @type  last_time: rospy.Time
        @param odom: Odometry instance to update.
        @type  odom: nav_msgs.msg.Odometry

        @return: transform
        @rtype: ( (float, float, float), (float, float, float, float) )
        """
        # based on otl_roomba by OTL <t.ogura@gmail.com>

        current_time = sensor_state.header.stamp
        dt = (current_time - last_time).to_sec()

        # On startup, Create can report junk readings
        if abs(sensor_state.distance) > 1.0 or abs(sensor_state.angle) > 1.0:
            raise Exception("Distance, angle displacement too big, invalid readings from robot. Distance: %.2f, Angle: %.2f" % (sensor_state.distance, sensor_state.angle))

        # this is really delta_distance, delta_angle
        d  = sensor_state.distance * self.odom_linear_scale_correction #correction factor from calibration
        angle = sensor_state.angle * self.odom_angular_scale_correction #correction factor from calibration

        x = cos(angle) * d
        y = -sin(angle) * d

        last_angle = self._pos2d.theta
        self._pos2d.x += cos(last_angle)*x - sin(last_angle)*y
        self._pos2d.y += sin(last_angle)*x + cos(last_angle)*y
        self._pos2d.theta += angle

        # Turtlebot quaternion from yaw. simplified version of tf.transformations.quaternion_about_axis
        odom_quat = (0., 0., sin(self._pos2d.theta/2.), cos(self._pos2d.theta/2.))

        # construct the transform
        transform = (self._pos2d.x, self._pos2d.y, 0.), odom_quat

        # update the odometry state
        odom.header.stamp = current_time
        odom.pose.pose   = Pose(Point(self._pos2d.x, self._pos2d.y, 0.), Quaternion(*odom_quat))
        odom.twist.twist = Twist(Vector3(d/dt, 0, 0), Vector3(0, 0, angle/dt))
        if sensor_state.requested_right_velocity == 0 and \
               sensor_state.requested_left_velocity == 0 and \
               sensor_state.distance == 0:
            odom.pose.covariance = ODOM_POSE_COVARIANCE2
            odom.twist.covariance = ODOM_TWIST_COVARIANCE2
        else:
            odom.pose.covariance = ODOM_POSE_COVARIANCE
            odom.twist.covariance = ODOM_TWIST_COVARIANCE

        # return the transform
        return transform

    def publish_odometry_transform(self, odometry):
        self.transform_broadcaster.sendTransform(
            (odometry.pose.pose.position.x, odometry.pose.pose.position.y, odometry.pose.pose.position.z),
            (odometry.pose.pose.orientation.x, odometry.pose.pose.orientation.y, odometry.pose.pose.orientation.z,
             odometry.pose.pose.orientation.w),
             odometry.header.stamp, odometry.child_frame_id, odometry.header.frame_id)

def connected_file():
    return os.path.join(rospkg.get_ros_home(), 'turtlebot-connected')

def turtlebot_main(argv):
    c = TurtlebotNode()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            # This sleep throttles reconnecting of the driver.  It
            # appears that pyserial does not properly release the file
            # descriptor for the USB port in the event that the Create is
            # unplugged from the laptop.  This file desecriptor prevents
            # the create from reassociating with the same USB port when it
            # is plugged back in.  The solution, for now, is to quickly
            # exit the driver and let roslaunch respawn the driver until
            # reconnection occurs.  However, it order to not do bad things
            # to the Create bootloader, and also to keep relaunching at a
            # minimum, we have a 3-second sleep.
            time.sleep(3.0)
            
            c.start()
            c.spin()

        except Exception as ex:
            msg = "Failed to contact device with error: [%s]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create."%(ex)
            c._diagnostics.node_status(msg,"error")
            rospy.logerr(msg)

        finally:
            # Driver no longer connected, delete flag from disk
            try:
                os.remove(connected_file())
            except Exception: pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    turtlebot_main(sys.argv)
```

I think that maybe is the comment line `#self.baudrate = rospy.get_param('~baudrate', self.default_baudrate)` but I don't know if it is correct to write it like this: `self.baudrate = rospy.get_param('~baudrate', 115200)` or I need to change the baudrate in another file.

Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247341/how-can-i-see-the-default-baud-rate-of-the-turtlebot_node.py-file?/) by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-05**:
`self.robot.start(self.port, robot_types.ROBOT_TYPES[self.robot_type].baudrate)` looks more promising; I think you should have a look through the robot_types module. (disclosure: I don't know anything about the create driver; I just read a lot of code)

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
Thanks a lot!!!

I'll check it

Greetings!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @ahendrix suggested the robot_type seems to encode the default baud rate: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/blob/indigo/create_node/src/create_node/robot_types.py#L46

If you set the parameter `~robot_type` parameter to `roomba` I suspect it will work as you want. From here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/blob/indigo/create_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py#L152

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Diana_Elyza](https://answers.ros.org/users/27895/diana_elyza/) on 2016-11-06**:
Thank you very much!!!

I will read these parameters.

Greetings!!!